# Flutter - Utilizar unico set de propriedades para varios containers

Tags: flutter, dart

Sou iniciante em Flutter/Dart.
Em uma de minhas práticas deparei com um "child: wrap" onde coloquei vários containers.
Em cada container coloquei a seguintes propriedades:

```
child: Wrap(
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        runSpacing: 10,
        spacing: 10,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: largura,
            height: altura,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black, //color of border
                  width: 1, //width of border
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
          ),
          Container(
            width: largura,
            height: altura,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.amber,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 2,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
          ),
```

A minha dúvida é:
Como faço para NÃO REPETIR as propriedades:valores do "decoration : BoxDecoration", uma vez que são repetidos para todos os containers que colocar? Algo como classes CSS.

Teria como gerar classes? Poderia utilizar variáveis? Seria o caso de utilizar Lista?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma variável do tipo *BoxDecoration*, caso os valores forem ser sempre constantes, ou criar um método que retorne sua estilização baseada em alguns valores que possam variar.

Deixei um exemplo abaixo com ambas as formas:

> Você pode usar o [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id) para testar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final _containerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.amber,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: 2,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  );
  
 BoxDecoration _containerDecorationWithColor(Color color) => BoxDecoration(
    color: color,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: 2,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: _containerDecoration,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: _containerDecoration,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: _containerDecorationWithColor(Colors.red),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

#### Boas práticas

Uma boa prática é que quando você for trabalhar com estilos, onde possam existir vários, que serão reaproveitados no projeto é você criar um arquivo apenas para armazenar esses estilos, deixando assim seu código mais organizado e limpo.

Caso queira pode fazer da seguinte forma também:

```
class EstiloContainers {
  final containerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.amber,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.black,
      width: 2,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  );

  BoxDecoration containerDecorationWithColor(Color color) => BoxDecoration(
        color: color,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black,
          width: 2,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      );
}
```

E para utilizar é simples, basta apenas instânciar a classe:

```
final estilos = EstiloContainers();
estilos.containerDecoration;
```

> Não entrarei em mais detalhes sobre o assunto aqui, mas para melhorar ainda mais a classe de
> estilos, ela poderia possuir métodos estáticos, para não precisar ser
> instânciada para acessar seus métodos.